# Sorting a list of tuplets linked with each other

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream

I want to ask a question about sorting in Java, to be precise i need to sort a list of tuples (that are defined as a custom class) but that are linked like a tree to each other.

Basically this is a list of document ids that express the relation parent-child, and are organized as sets (possibly unordered). The tuples are **already filtered to have unique left / right elements**, so that the tree has unique links between documents (they are not allowed to have multiple leafs).

Using example data, i have this kind of list: `[(1,2), (3,4), (0,1), (2,3)]`, this represents the following tree:

```
0
|_ 1
   |_ 2
      |_ 3
         |_ 4
```

Hence i need the list to be ordered as follow: `[(0,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,4)]`.

I also add that **it's possible that the parent document id is greater than the child one**, so a simple sorting based on which id is greater is not possible.

I tried using the `.sorted()` method of the Stream class, after making the custom class comparable and adding the following code:

```java
    @Override
    public int compareTo(DocumentIdVersionsStack o) {
        if (parentDocumentId == o.getChildDocumentId()) return  1;
        if (childDocumentId == o.getParentDocumentId()) return  -1;
        return 0;
    }
```

Basically telling it to invert the order if the current one is child of the other tuple and vice versa, but the list is still not what i expect it to be.

Any idea on how to do this using streams? I didn't want to use complex sortings methods that require recursion, just to keep the code cleaner, but if it can't be done otherwise i'll check that.

Thank you!

**EDIT:**
I'll add a couple of informations:

- The tuples are already contiguous, there won't be 'holes' of missing ids
- The recursion (last id = first id) is again taken care before passing the tuples to the sorting method
- There will be a tuple with the left value not found in any of the right values -> this will be the first element after the sort
- There will be a tuple with the right value not found in any of the left values -> this will be the last element after sort
- All left and right values are unique, they are just linked as explained before (left1 = right2 and so on)

Comment: sorry - forgot to add (i'll add now) - it is kind of a map, so it is already excluded that there can be multiple tuples with the same left or right key.
This means that in case that a list like yours is passed it will throw an exception before proceeding with the sort.

Comment: And how about this `[(1,2), (3,4), (0,1)]` (missing) and this `[(1,2), (2-4), (3,5)]` (crossed)?

Comment: Similarly those will be split before sorting, so those will be considered as different lists with only the contiguous parts being sorted individually

Comment: `[(0,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,4)]` can be placed a linked list. `(node_value, next_node_value)` , just read starting from top (assume the chain is properly added)

Comment: In that case, all you need is to sort by the "left" value in the touple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mentioned that the tuples are unique. So the `compareTo` method will not work as it deals with "equal" elements as well, which is not applicable to a unique list. In the current `compareTo` code, the tuples (1,2) and (3,4) would be treated as equals which is why it is not returning expected results. Also since parent id could be greater than child id, you cannot clearly say if (1,2) is greater or less than (3,4).
The order could be `(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)` or `(3,4), (4,1), (1,2)`. Hence without knowing the details of other nodes, it might not be possible to do it using `compareTo`.

I would suggest an approach to keep a map of these tuples with the parent id as the key, then find the root node and start traversing from root:

```java
Map<Integer, DocumentIdVersionsStack> map = list.stream()//
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(DocumentIdVersionsStack::getParentId,
                                          Function.identity()));

Set<Integer> child = list.stream()
                         .map(DocumentIdVersionsStack::getChildId)
                         .collect(Collectors.toSet());


// Get the root node
DocumentIdVersionsStack node = list.stream()
                                   .filter(u -> !child.contains(u.getParentId()))
                                   .findFirst()
                                   .orElse(null);
List<DocumentIdVersionsStack> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add(node);
// Traverse using the map
while (map.containsKey(node.getChildId())) {
    node = map.get(node.getChildId());
    list2.add(node);
}
System.out.println(list2);
```

Comment: Nice, this works really well. Thank you!
I was able to finally implement it by using a recursive method, but this is way more coincise (and kinda clean to read).